# ESP32 SPIFFS Write problem

Tags: esp8266, esp32, esp, spiffs

I'm trying to flash a spiffs on a esp32 but it is not working, i'm using these commands from this [source](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/spiffs.html):

to create the image:

```
mkspiffs -c /data/ -b 4096 -p 256 -s 0x100000 spiffs.bin
```

my output was this:

```
/test.txt
```

looks it worked.

to flash the image:

```
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyCH341USB0 --baud 115200 write_flash -z 0x110000 spiffs.bin
```

and the output:

```
esptool.py v4.7.dev3
Serial port /dev/ttyCH341USB0
Connecting...
Failed to get PID of a device on /dev/ttyCH341USB0, using standard reset sequence.
.
Detecting chip type... Unsupported detection protocol, switching and trying again...
Connecting...
Failed to get PID of a device on /dev/ttyCH341USB0, using standard reset sequence.
.
Detecting chip type... ESP32
Chip is ESP32-D0WD (revision v1.0)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: c4:4f:33:24:4f:49
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00110000 to 0x0020ffff...
Compressed 1048576 bytes to 2025...
Wrote 1048576 bytes (2025 compressed) at 0x00110000 in 3.2 seconds (effective 2592.1 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

To test the file system im using this code to list all files:

```
  File root = SPIFFS.open("/");
  File file = root.openNextFile()
  while(file){
    Serial.print("FILE: ");
    Serial.println(file.name());
    file = root.openNextFile();
  }
```

the image is not being written, when i use this [arduino plugin](https://github.com/me-no-dev/arduino-esp32fs-plugin) it works fine, but if i run the esptool write command the files are not overrided.

can someone help-me?

Comment: How do you know the Arduino Plugin works and the ESP tool doesn't? How do you check that the image has been flashed?

Comment: @NickS. using a program to list all files, i've edited the question with it.